# Toggle button in menu

Tags: javascript

I have a menu which is creating from the code:

```
document.getElementById('menu').innerHTML += "<li onClick=\"icon_content(" + m + ",'" + image + "','" + name + "')\"><a href=\"#\">" + name + "<\/a><\/li>";
```

It's in loop and the result is 5 buttons.
It is workig fine but I would to add toggle effect for that. For example changing the button color. When I used:

```
document.getElementById('menu').style.color='red';
```

It changed whole menu but I want only button which I clicked. 
Is it possible?

Comment: Did you call that in your onClick function?

Answer (score 0):

That would be done in your event callback, `icon_content()`. For which, it's better to handle the events centrally rather than inline `onclick` attributes. So:

```
document.getElementById('menu').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName == 'LI') {
        /* your other code here */
        evt.target.style.background = 'red';
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Should i put that inside icon_conent() function ? It is not working. :(.